# how to change legend shape in google charts?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am new to angularjs and google charts ,i want to make the legend shape square for pie charts by default it is circle.here is my code:
here is my code in Index.HTML:

```
 <head>
   <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <script src="http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div style="padding-left:100px">
        my pig pie chart</div>
 <div google-chart chart="chart" style="width:400,height:300"></div>
 </body>
```

Script.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'googlechart' ]);

     app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      var chart1 = {};
      chart1.type = "PieChart";
      chart1.data = [
       ['Component', 'cost'],
       ['Software hardware and electrice', 50000],
       ['Hardware', 80000]
  ];
       chart1.data.push(['Services',20000]);
        chart1.options = {
       'legend':'right',
        'width':400,
        'height':300
   };
  chart1.formatters = {
      number : [{
      columnNum: 1,
      pattern: "$ #,##0.00"
    }]
  };

   $scope.chart = chart1;

     $scope.aa=1*$scope.chart.data[1][1];
    $scope.bb=1*$scope.chart.data[2][1];
    $scope.cc=1*$scope.chart.data[3][1];
});
```

any suggestion guide me how can i do this.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documented option for this. Pie charts render as SVG, and the little circle is a `<circle>` tag, so you could not do this with CSS.

It MAY be possible do do this with DOM manipulation in JQuery or something like it, but since the google charts API does not render chart elements with classes or ID's on anything, whatever you came up with would be very fragile and may be easily broken by changes to the charts API or to your chart itself.

It is my opinion that this falls under the category of "Things that would be nice but are not worth the effort."